# Calculate direct dependencies among values of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dependencies

A data frame is given and the objective is to calculate the direct dependency value between two columns of the data frame.

```
c1  c2   N
a    b   30
a    c   5
a    d   10
c    a   5
b    a   10
```

what we are looking for is that to get the direct dependency relations, for example, for `a`and `b` this value is `ab - ba = 20`.
The final result should be like this:

```
c1  c2   N     DepValue
a    b   30    ab - ba = 20
a    c   5     ac - ca = 0
a    d   10    ad- 0 = 10
c    a   5     ca - ac= 0
b    a   10    ba - ab = 20
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @jogo mistake :\

Comment: ab - ba will always be 0.  Eg, 5*4 - 4*5 = 20 - 20 = 0.  Your question isn't clear.

Comment: @user1945827 I am not looking for the multiplication of the values in columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
D <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text=
"c1  c2   N
a    b   30
a    c   5
a    d   10
c    a   5
b    a   10")

N12 <- D$N
names(N12) <- paste0(D$c1, D$c2)
N21 <- N12[paste0(D$c2, D$c1)]
D$depValue <- D$N - ifelse(is.na(N21), 0, N21)
```

result:

```
> D
  c1 c2  N depValue
1  a  b 30       20
2  a  c  5        0
3  a  d 10       10
4  c  a  5        0
5  b  a 10      -20
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create groups with `pmin` and `pmax` values of `c1` and `c2` and take difference between the two values. This will return `NA` for groups with only one value, we can `replace` those `NA`s to the first value in the group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group1 = pmin(c1, c2), group2 = pmax(c1, c2)) %>%
  mutate(dep = N[1] - N[2], 
         dep = replace(dep, is.na(dep), N[1])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group1, -group2)

#   c1    c2      N   dep
#  <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
#1 a     b        30    20
#2 a     c         5     0
#3 a     d        10    10
#4 c     a         5     0
#5 b     a        10    20
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea via base R is to sort columns `c1` and `c2`, split based on those values and subtract `N`, i.e.

```
i1 <- paste(pmin(df$c1, df$c2), pmax(df$c1, df$c2))
i1
#[1] "a b" "a c" "a d" "a c" "a b"

do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, i1), function(i) {i['DepValue'] <- Reduce(`-`, i$N); i}))
#      c1 c2  N DepValue
#a b.1  a  b 30       20
#a b.5  b  a 10       20
#a c.2  a  c  5        0
#a c.4  c  a  5        0
#a d    a  d 10       10
```